# In lumen i want to add custom response for any exception

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I added custom response into render method of handler.php like this:

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{

    //$e->getTraceAsString();
    $result['response']= 'false';
    $result['exception']=$e->getMessage();

    return response()->json($result);
   /* return parent::render($request,$e);*/
}
```

if  i update anything using composer ,will it be removed? 
there is any way to override handler class ?

Comment: `if i update anything using composer ,will it be removed?` no

Answer (score 0):

[composer update](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#update) command will command to composer for generates a file called composer.lock which lists all your packages and the currently installed versions.

However, you can run `composer update --no-scripts`, this will run the composer update but will skip over the scripts added to the file.